# Is the DJI Windows 10 SDK UWP-specific?

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

Does anyone know if the DJI Windows 10 SDK is specific to UWP, or can it be used in any .Net Core application? UWP is restrictive when it comes to interprocess communications, which limits sharing telemetry and video with pre-existing (non-UWP) applications. Just thought I'd ask the community before spending my client's money investigating.

Comment: The DJI SDK does appear to be bound to UWP; you can build a runtime, but it will throw an exception when you attempt to get an instance of DJISDKManager because it cannot find the Windows runtime type DJIWindowsWrapper.DJIWindowsNetworkHandle.

Comment: I am doing the same thing with an onboard PC and I believe this can be accomplished using the Windows QT Sample Application (depending on the model you have). I converted the project to Visual C using the Qt Visual Studio Tools. I am using the UART interface of LightBridge hardware. I have the choice of passing the video though the LB gimble connector and/or the LB HDMI/AV input.